# nutch is not working properly

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

Hello guys I am new in Nutch for web crawling.I followed the steps on 
[Nutch official site tutorial.](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)
I typed the **command in terminal** 
**$  bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/ urls/ TestCrawl/  2**
where urls has seed file contains website name and TestCrawl is my db directory.

It's giving me error with exit value 255.I am not sure what error is this.So I am posting my terminal screen shot here.[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you build nutch using `ant clean` and `ant runtime` commands ?
If yes then rather than running nutch via nutch located in `$NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch` use the from located inside `$NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/bin/nutch`.

If not then first build run using `ant runtime` command.
HTH.